# Image database organization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, database-design, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am curious as to how I should organize image storage in my application. They will be stored on disk somewhere, with the path / url stored in the database, but my application has become complex and image organization is leaving me baffled. The technology I am using is ASP.NET MVC 3 + EF 4.1 Code First (which is proving to be difficult with complex relationships).

This is a family based application, so there is a Family table, Member table, and a FamilyMember table to link to two. There is also a FamilyEvent, and MemberEvent table to track events in the family or member's life.

**Use cases**

A Member can upload multiple profile pictures (possibly to be put in a "profile" album?)

A Member can upload "family" photos, to be attached to the Family object, and put into some type of album for the family.

A Member can add a member event, and attach **multiple** images to the members event.

A Member can add a family event, and attach **multiple** images to the family's event.

These are the base use cases.

**My thoughts**

Base "Picture" table with id, description, and maybe the user id of the uploader.

MemberProfilePicture table with id, pictureId, memberId, etc...

MemberEventPicture table with id, pictureId, [member id?], membereventid, etc...

FamilyEventPicture table with id, pictureId, [familyId ?], familyeventid, etc...

This would allow a family or member to essentially "link" a Picture later to another profile pic / member event / or family event.

**My question**

Is this correct, or am I over-complicating this? I don't see any other way other than multiple tables to represent images for different things, which all refer to the base Picture table.  Can anyone give any suggestions as to how I can improve this model? While I understand there may be many definitions to correct, I'm looking for solutions as far as how to organize the imaging aspect of my application, or improvements on what I have already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is have three tables.

The 'picture' table which stores a unique id for each picture and the location.
The 'profile' table which has your dtails about the profile.
A third 'linking' table composed of pictureId and profileId

If I want to link picture A to profile X I just add in "A,X" to the linking table. Same thing for events or whatever. If there's going to be a many-to-many relationship this is the cleanest way to go (I'm assuming that the same picture can be in multiple profiles).

Hope I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: So essentially what I proposed is the way to go. Picture table, ProfilePicture, MemberPicture, FamilyEventPicture tables, etc...

Comment: You don't need more than one XXXXXPicture table . You can put an 'enum' of sorts if you want one linker.

Comment: How do you mean? You say I can link picture A to profile X with a linking table (say ProfilePicture). Wouldn't that be the same for say an event? A linking table for events and pictures (EventPicture)?

Answer (score 2):

Your using EF Code First so let's talk code not tables. You can realize your use cases by having only one Picture class and associate many Pictures with Member, Family and so on.

Taking this code

```
public class Family
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }
}

public class Picture
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Location { get; set; }
}
```

Will generate 3 Tables, Families, Members, Pictures with the Pictures table having two foreign keys Family_Id and Member_Id. This model allows to associated a single picture with Member, Family or both.

From a scalability point of view I would avoid to store the image binary in the database and using an ORM to access the binary. Better ideas are to store the picture in the file system or a "specialized" server like MongoDBs GridFS.

Comment: But doesn't tying the picture to a specific member and/or family limit my solution? Also, why would the Picture table have a FK to Member and Family, wouldn't that limit me to one picture each?

Comment: You can associate a picture to a family or member or both so it does not limit your solution.